# Storing data from inspect element to mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, google-maps-api-3

I'm having trouble on storing data to mysql database. Whenever I click the save button, the data that is needed to be stored in the database only appears at the inspect element window. I want the data to appear on database, not in the inspect element. Thank you in advance. Here is my code.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Maintenance</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
        #map_canvas { height: 100% }
        /* bootstrap fix */
        #map_canvas img {
            max-width: none;
        }
    </style> 

<!-- Google Maps and Places and Drawing API -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,drawing&sensor=false"></script>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.yohman.com/students/yoh/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="http://www.yohman.com/students/yoh/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- ArcGIS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.yohman.com/scripts/arcgislink.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//declare namespace
var up206b = {};

//declare map
var map;

//set the drawing manager
var drawingManager;

function trace(message)
{
    if (typeof console != 'undefined')
    {
        console.log(message);
    }
}

//Function that gets run when the document loads
up206b.initialize = function()
{
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.070264, -118.4440562);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false //disable the map type control
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    //add the drawing tool that allows users to draw points on the map
    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER]
        },
        markerOptions: {
            // icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('bus.png'),
            draggable: true
        }
    });

    //add the tools to the map
    drawingManager.setMap(map);

    //event listener that does the following after user draws point on the map
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (point) 
    {
        //"clone" the save-form to put in the infowindow
        var form =  $(".save-form").clone().show();
        var infowindow_content = form[0];
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: infowindow_content
        });

        //make each marker clickable
        google.maps.event.addListener(point.overlay, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,point.overlay);
        });

        //open infowindow by default
        infowindow.open(map,point.overlay);

        //when user clicks on the "submit" button
        form.submit({point: point}, function (event) {
            //prevent the default form behavior (which would refresh the page)
            event.preventDefault();

            //put all form elements in a "data" object
            var data = {
                name: $("input[name=name]", this).val(),
                description: $("textarea[name=description]", this).val(),
                category: $("select[name=category]",this).val(),
                lat: event.data.point.overlay.getPosition().lat(),
                lon: event.data.point.overlay.getPosition().lng()
            };
            trace(data)

            //send the results to the PHP script that adds the point to the database
            $.post("adddata.php", data, up206b.saveStopResponse, "json");

            //Erase the form and replace with new message
            infowindow.setContent('done')
            return false;
        });
    });

}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="up206b.initialize()">
    <!-- side panel div container -->
    <div style="position:absolute; width:380px; height: 100%; overflow:auto; float:left; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;"> 

        <div class="hero-unit">
            <h1>Enya:</h1>
            <p>A tour guiding application: Maintenance</p>
        </div>

<!--
            This is the form that will show up in the infowindow for
            each marker created.  The display is set to "none" by default
        -->
        <form class="form-horizontal save-form" style="display: none">
            <h1>Add me!</h1>
            <fieldset>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="category">What is this?</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <select name="category">
                            <option value="asset">something I like</option>
                            <option value="deficit">something I do not like</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="description">Description</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <textarea class="input-xlarge" name="description" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save me</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>


    </div>
    <!-- map div container -->
    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%; margin-left:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

adddata.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

//database access info
$db = new MySQLi("localhost", "root", "", "_up206b");

$statement = $db->stmt_init();

//database insert statement
$statement->prepare("INSERT INTO public (lat, lon, name, description, category) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

//grab values from the url and add to database
$statement->bind_param("ddsss", &$_POST['lat'], &$_POST['lon'], &$_POST['name'], &$_POST['description'], &$_POST['category']);
$status = $statement->execute();

//create a status message
if ($status)
{
    $message = array("message" => $_POST['name'] . " has been added!");
}
else
{
    $message = array("error" => $db->error);
}

$statement->close();

echo json_encode($message);
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the error logs? [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: are your lat, lon fields of type DOUBLE?

Comment: Yes, my lat and lon are declared as double.